# What are the font names for the arcade python library?

Tags: python, text, fonts, drawing, arcade

I am new to arcade (and python), I'm trying to get some text to be in the Comic Sans MS font but my text shows up as the default font. Here's the line of code for the text : 
`arcade.draw_text("test", 138, 492, (250, 250, 250), 58, font_name='Comic Sans MS')`

It seems that the font names in arcade have been replaced by shortened versions (e.g : 'Garamond' is 'GARA'), maybe this could be what I'm doing wrong?

Can anyone provide a list of all the shortened font names or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pythonarcade/comments/aalhjd/documentation_on_fonts_available_with_draw_font/) post, it seems that only **.ttf** fonts are supported.

I realized that you should not use the font "name" (i.e Comic Sans MS), but instead use the **font-file** name (i.e comic.ttf):

```
arcade.draw_text("test", 138, 492, (250, 250, 250), 58, font_name='comic')
```

If you are using Windows, you can find the list of fonts in Settings/Personalization/Fonts. Click each font to check out its file-name.

I also noticed that some font names only work when in capital letters, e.g *GARA*, while some work in small letters only, e.g *bgothl* for BankGothic Lt BT. Trial and error should help you find the font you need.